# width issue with span and a tag

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with the width of the link with a span tag within it you can see it here:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQUvj/)

You can see that link 2 has a bigger width then the visual suggests? Any idea how whats going on here?

Link 1 also has a very wide width but is hidden between link 2.

Comment: why are you using "position: absolute"?

Comment: position relative I am using I believe.

Comment: ahh it's only happening in firefox*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rendering correctly, I guess you mismatched your flow with border colors, you must be looking for this?

Nothing's wrong for me

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQUvj/3/)

Edit: Note you've given borders to `span` and not `a`, if that's the point it should be [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQUvj/4/) because `<a>` will take up `100%` width because it is a block level element

Comment: Try firefox my version is 15.0.1

Comment: @Anicho haha, `<a>` element is a block level element, it takes up 100% of width, so you can use `display: inline-block;` or simply style your `a` element instead of spans